# How to precache assets with names that change at every deploy using service workers?

Tags: service-worker, sw-precache, service-worker-events

We're working with Workbox to precache some assets of the "next" page, but our assets URL contains the date and the hash of the deploy. E.g. "/css/2019-05-15/f00ba5/home.css".

The problem we're facing is how to pass the changing portion of URL ("2019-05-15/f00ba5") to the service worker, and make Workbox to precache the list of assets.

We're using Workbox and we tried workbox-window to send a message from the web page to the SW and until here... it worked!

But now that the SW knows the hash, we don't know how to take advantage of it, because if we call the workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute() method from inside the event listener, the import of the workbox.precaching module fails somehow.

In the page.html

```html
<script type="module">
    import {Workbox} from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.0.0/workbox-window.prod.mjs';

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const wb = new Workbox('/service-worker.js');
        wb.messageSW({type: 'hash', payload: "12345"});
        wb.register();
    })
}
</script>
```

In the service-worker.js

```js
const file1 = "/css/{hash}/home.css";
const file2 = "/js/{hash}/home.js";
const file3 = "/img/{hash}/hero.jpg";

addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.type === 'hash') {
        // TODO: replace {hash} with event.data.payload in file1, 2, 3
        const precacheManifest = [ file1, file2, file3 ];
        workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(precacheManifest);
    }
});
```

I get the error

```
workbox-sw.js:1 Unable to import module 'workbox-precaching' from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js'.
loadModule @ workbox-sw.js:1
get @ workbox-sw.js:1
(anonymous) @ service-worker.js:39
workbox-sw.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js' failed to load.
at Object.loadModule (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js:1:954)
at Object.get (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js:1:727)
at https://brioni.f31.lcl/service-worker.js:39:13
loadModule @ workbox-sw.js:1
get @ workbox-sw.js:1
(anonymous) @ service-worker.js:39
framework.js:1441 STORE::LazyLoad.Init
```

I expect that to work and precache the files in the `precacheManifest` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error that you're running into is due to a restriction around callimg `importScripts()` after service worker installation has taken place, which happens under the hood via the `workbox-sw` library. It's described in more detail in the [Workbox documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started#importing_workbox), along with alternative ways of accomplishing the same thing.

That being said, using `workbox-precaching` "dynamically" isn't a good choice. As described in the [`workbox-precaching` documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list), you should use a build tool, like `workbox-cli` or `workbox-webpack-plugin`, to generate this list and automatically insert the precache manifest into your service worker file. Changes to your service worker file due to an updated precache manifest will trigger the service worker update lifecycle events, and that will, in turn, make sure that your precache assets are kept up to date.

If you don't want to use a build tool and generate a precache manifest in advance, then setting up [routing rules](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests) and using a runtime caching strategy is more appropriate than precaching. You can use `workbox-window` to [pass in a list of URLs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window#example-cache-urls) that you want cached at runtime.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your explanation, that's a little bit clearer than the documentation alone.

Unfortunately our build process which generates the hash is out of our reach and I'm afraid it can't produce a new file to deploy at that stage.

We'll probably use our server-side language to generate the service-worker.js file, since the server knows the deploy hash to put in the URL.

Comment: personally my SW call a `version.json` which contain file to fetch, and an hash to know if there a any difference, i'd prefere that that killing and installing/activate a new SW each time I deploy